# Converting a negative number created by toHexString back to an int in Java

Tags: java, integer, hex, unsigned-integer

I am getting an error because of the following line of code:

```java
int x = color(Integer.parseInt("ffffffde",16));
```

The value "ffffffde" is being created by the following code:

```java
Integer.toHexString(int_val);
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ffffffde"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
```

I think it might be because it is a negative value.

Any ideas why or how or how to fix it?

---

Edit:

Turns out it is a known bug [JDK-4215269](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4215269) in versions of Java prior to 8.

Although you can convert integers to hex strings, you cannot convert them back if they are negative numbers!

Comment: An error?  Wonder what that might be.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ffffffde` is bigger than integer max value

> [Java int is 32 bit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) signed type ranges from –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

```
ffffffde = 4,294,967,262
```

### Edit

You used `Integer.toHexString(int_val)` to turn a int into a hex string. From the doc of that method:

> Returns a string representation of the integer argument as an **unsigned** integer in base 16.

But `int` is a **signed** type.

**USE**

```
int value = new BigInteger("ffffffde", 16).intValue();
```

to get it back as a negative value.

Comment: Right `4294967262` is out of `int` range

Comment: But the value is being created by using "Integer.toHexString(int_val)"

Comment: `+1` good answer, by the way I also knew the person [you are talking here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176318/what-is-considered-incorrect-tagging).

Answer (score 5):

If you are getting error like this,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ffffffde"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:461)
    at com.TestStatic.main(TestStatic.java:22)
```

Then there is problem with value you are passing that is **ffffffde** . This is not a valid hex value for parsing to int.

Please try this

```
int x = Integer.parseInt("ffffde",16);
        System.out.println(x);
```

It should work.

For hex values more than that you have to pars to **Long**

```
Long x = Long.parseLong("ffffffde",16);
        System.out.println(x);
```

And this also should work

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`Integer.parseUnsignedInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseUnsignedInt(java.lang.String,int)) method introduced in Java 8 instead of `Integer.parseInt` will result in the desired behavior.

```java
int x = color(Integer.parseUnsignedInt("ffffffde", 16));
```

The issue is that `Integer.toHexString` returns an unsigned integer in base 16, but `Integer.parseInt` parses the value as a signed integer.  Since `ffffffde` as a signed integer is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, the observed `NumberFormatException` is thrown.

The `Integer.toHexString` [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString(int)) indicates that `parseUnsignedInt` can be used to convert the `String` back to an `int`:

> The value of the argument can be recovered from the returned string `s` by calling [`Integer.parseUnsignedInt(s, 16)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseUnsignedInt(java.lang.String,int)).